# How to handle Unicode (Hindi) characters in URLs while sharing on Twitter or Facebook?

Tags: unicode, facebook, twitter, social-networking

I have a website in Hindi language. When i try to share a post or page on twitter using social share button it shows strange on twitter something like this:

[image]

Is there any way to fix it permanently?

Comment: That *is* part of the URL.

Comment: Those character can be replaced with the real ones. Like if there is `%26` then it can be replaced by `&`. See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding

Comment: I know its related with unicode characters. I am asking how to fix it?

Comment: Twitter can't show special characters in links, instead it converts them. There is no way to "fix" it.

Comment: its not lnk, its just a heading. i fixed the link problem by shortening it. but how to fix the heading problem

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to write Hindi in the URL section of your website or block but to fix the above problem you can follow the steps that are stated below:

1. Since URL accepts only English language so you must be trying to use your title in English language before publishing the page or post of your blog. You can update it later.
2. Write your post in the language you want but keep in mind that the language of the title must be in English language before publishing your post or page because once the URL is created it can't be changed by changing anything in that particular post or page.
3. Once your post or page is published with English title and URL, You can update the language of the title or content of your post or page in the language you want.

It will not affect your URL or content in any way.

Answer (score -2):

I observed that there is no way to use Hindi in URL. Using Hindi in URL is also not good SEO practices. So use English(Good for SEO) or post id in URL.